# How to call web services with ant build.xml?

Tags: svn, ant

I am using ANT for svn purpose. Now I want to call my RESTful webservice inside build.xml and use it response for further process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ant get task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html)

Another possibility is to execute curl using [ant exec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,I used curl but I got the response in my browser,how do I get it in my build.xml itself.